# Alarm Manager do not fire at the accurate time

Tags: flutter, android-alarms

My alarm manager in flutter does not fire at the accurate time. Sometimes it is upto 5 minutes late and sometimes I have to get the phone to wake up before it fires.
How can I make the alarm more accurate and fire without failure. I am using it to get the location of a moving car and the 5 minutes failure window is a very long time.

Below is my code..

```
      Future<void> _locateDriver() async {
        await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
        await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(const Duration(minutes: 1), helloAlarmID,
            printLocation, wakeup: true, exact: true, rescheduleOnReboot:true).then((val) => print(val));
          ------
      }
```

My android manifest looks like this.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<application
    android:name=".Application"
    android:label="xxxxxx"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

    <service
        android:name="io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.AlarmService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        android:exported="false"/>
    <receiver
        android:name="io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.AlarmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false"/>
    <receiver
        android:name="io.flutter.plugins.androidalarmmanager.RebootBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and where i print the location to mqtt is here.

```
  static void printLocation() async{
    Isolate.current.hashCode;
    print(await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high));
    mqttSendCoordinates(await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high));

    new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 20), () async {
      print(await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high));
      mqttSendCoordinates(await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high));
    });

    new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 40), () async {
      print(await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high));
      mqttSendCoordinates(await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high));
    });

  }
```

Comment: which android version do you use?

Comment: I am using Version 9

Comment: I reverted to creating an android native app. This allows me to use alarm manager with setExact and setExactWhileIdle functions.